# What dialect are these numbers from?

Tags: dialects, numbers

In the ending for the anime "Kumamiko: Girl Meets Bear", there's a line where the backup singers (aka the residents of Kumade Village) say

いず　ぬっ　さん　すう　でーじぇーへーうぃーごー

Which I haven't seen translated, but it's pretty clearly "One, two, three, four, DJ here we go" to my ears. [YouTube clip for reference](https://youtu.be/L1BWdO7ypJM?t=45s)

I'm curious as to what dialect they're using for the numbers - the show is set in a presumably fictional town in northern Honshu, so I would assume some variant of Tōhoku-ben or similar?

Comment: Here are [the official lyrics](http://www.uta-net.com/song/208574/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like typical 東北弁 (Tōhoku dialect) to me, in that

- Standard [i] sounds like [u].
- Many unvoiced consonants become voiced.

Typically, わたし sounds closer to わだす in 東北弁.

See [Tōhoku dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C5%8Dhoku_dialect) on Wikipedia. [This answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/680/5010) also explains the characteristics of 東北弁 well.

Comment: Somehow, despite me trying to look for info on how Tōhoku dialect pronounces numbers, I never saw that Wikipedia article that practically spells it out. Seems to be nearly an open-and-shut case, then. I'm guessing that there isn't enough information to narrow it down to a subdialect?

Comment: いず、ぬ、さん、す is used in [this video](http://videotopics.yahoo.co.jp/videolist/official/sports/pa07838e5197b1bd6c387d2ed47182059), too. Recently very few people speak fluent Tohoku-ben, and I doubt this was written by someone who is good at subdialect of Tohoku-ben (The lyricist seems to be from Nagoya).

Comment: Makes sense to me :) Thanks for the answer!